# react-router connected to redux : works with links but only the URL change when dispatching push

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, connected-react-router

I'm trying to programmatically push an URL to navigate with react-router, redux, and connected-react-router

When clicking on a `<Link />` button, it's working great, the URL is changing and the route too.

But when using a `dispatch(push(url))`, the URL only change and the content is not updated

I've made a minimal example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvznjm8mz3).

Any help would be really grateful,

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

A lot of anti-pattern code, poor application structured, and mixing of packages is holding your application back.

I rewrote it entirely, here's what I've done:

1. Reconfigured your application folder's structure to be standard.
2. Don't mix `Router` (`BrowserRouter`) with `ConnectedRouter`.
3. Don't place all of your `components` within the `App.js` file.
4. Since the `Header` is always mounted, you don't need `redux`, instead you can just use `withRouter` (it exposes route props to the component).
5. Your `rootReducer` is missing a `reducer`, so I added a `dummyReducer` that just returns `state`.
6. Stick to `Link` or `this.props.history` when navigating. For this example, there's no need to use both. Also, you don't need to use `ConnectedRouter`'s `push` function, because the `history` is passed as a prop when using `withRouter`.

Side note: If you want the `Header` to be a "router" where all route changes pass through here, then you'll need to create an `action` and a `reducer` that passes a `string` and stores it to the redux's `store`. The `Header` is then `connect`ed to the redux store and updates the `route` when this `string` has changed.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/526p7kjqq4

**components/Header.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends PureComponent {
  goTo = route => {
    this.props.history.push(route);
  };

  render = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => this.goTo("/")}> Announcements </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => this.goTo("/shopping")}> Shopping </button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.goTo("/shopping")}>
          Click here to go shopping ! (if you can...)
        </button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Header);
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Announcements from "../components/annoucements";
import Shopping from "../components/shopping";

export default () => (
  <div style={{ padding: "150px" }}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Announcements} />
      <Route path="/shopping" component={Shopping} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

**components/App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Routes from "../routes";
import Header from "./Header";

export default () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Header />
    <Routes />
  </Fragment>
);
```

---

Here is what you're trying to accomplish: https://codesandbox.io/s/8nmp95y8r2

However, I **DO NOT** recommend this as it's a bit unnecessary, when `history` is either already passed as a prop from the `Route` or can be exposed when using `withRouter`. According to the Redux [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md#deep-integration), it's not recommended either. And instead to either use `Link` or pass the `history` prop to the redux `action` creator instead of programmatic navigation through redux state.

**containers/Header.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { push } from "connected-react-router";

class Header extends PureComponent {
  goTo = route => this.props.push(route); // this is equivalent to this.props.dispatch(push(route)) -- I'm just appending dispatch to the push function in the connect function below

  render = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => this.goTo("/")}> Announcements </button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button onClick={() => this.goTo("/shopping")}> Shopping </button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.goTo("/shopping")}>
          Click here to go shopping ! (if you can...)
        </button>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { push }
)(Header);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. You have to know that this "example" is just a reaaaally small part of something bigger, and extremly simplified for the example.

> Also, don't use ConnectedRouter's push function.

can you tell me why ? 

The thing is, I don't get what you changed (appart all the application) to make it work. There are a lot of discussion we could have about application structuring, but that wasn't my case here.
Thanks for having taken some times to answer me

Comment: I've included all the changes above. Please be more specific about which part(s) you don't understand. Since you're utilizing `history` with `ConnectedRouter`, but trying to push to a new location in `ConnectedRouter` (and not updating `history`), there's a mismatch in the routing. See history API: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v3/docs/GettingStarted.md#navigation

Comment: Updated the answer to include a second option, although it's not recommended.

Comment: Hi, I know that what you did "works", but I don't get why you had to rewrite all to make it work.
You just had to say something like "Why do you use `BrowserRouter` and `ConnectedRouter`, and why do you create two instances of history ?

And then, give the same example I had but with just these two modifications : https://codesandbox.io/s/p2wp49mmp0

I still don't get why I shouldn't use `push` provided by `connected-react-router`. I mean, that's [how they tell to do](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-navigate-with-redux-action).

Comment: I sure won't use the `dispatch` when I can use a `<Link />` but I also use `saga` and sometimes, you have to programmatically go to a new route. Again, my example wasn't my whole app, just a tiny part of it

Answer (score 0):

After reading the complete thread [react-router-redux's push() not rendering new route](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4924), I came across this solution  you need to use Router with passing down history as prop down to your app and don't use create from multiple files just import it from a common file.

Here is the working codesandbox: [push rendering the new route](https://codesandbox.io/s/x2688xv54w)

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer as `ConnectedRouter` is supposed to replace `Router` and `BrowserRouter`. This is a hacky solution that should be avoided and isn't recommended by redux: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md#deep-integration.